# Как вставить запись в таблицу в разные столбцы из двух таблиц?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, insert

Мне необходимо вставить запись в таблицу в разные столбцы из 2 таблиц.

Использовать что-то вида:

```sql
insert into table (p1, p2)
(запрос), (запрос);
```

Т.е. часть столбцов должна быть заполнена из первого запроса, а часть из второго.

Какая конструкция правильная для такого варианта?

Или мне необходимо обязательно связывать эти 2-а запроса с `join`?

Имею ввиду вот это:

```sql
insert into table (column 1, column2)
values(select column1 from table1),(select column2 from table2)`
```

PS СУБД Oralce, если это имеет значение.

Comment: Каждый из подзапросов возвращает набор записей. А набор записей в одно поле одной записи не лезет ну никак... Мне кажется, что Вы в попытке упростить вопрос сделали его совершенно неадекватным.

Comment: @Akina у меня есть некие проблемы с пояснениями, я согласен, но суть такова, чтобы с двух запросов вставить в одну запись таблицы

Comment: Я верно понимаю, что каждый из подзапросов возвращает строго одну запись?

Comment: _или мне необходимо обязательно связывать эти 2 запроса джоинами_ - почему бы нет? В листе `values` запросы нельзя указывать.

Comment: @0xdb я воспользовался вашим примером в ответе, связывать эти 2 запроса не стал

Comment: @Sosiska Запрос для вставки всегда **один**. Если в нём есть две или более таблицы, то они в каком то роде "связаны", это не обязательно join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте этот рабочий пример:

```sql
create table tab3 (id number, col1 varchar2 (16), col2 varchar2 (16));

insert into tab3 (id, col1, col2)
with tab1 (id, col1) as (
    select 1, 'val1' from dual 
),
tab2 (id, col2) as (
    select 1, 'val2' from dual 
)
select 3, col1, col2
from tab1 join tab2 on tab2.id = tab1.id;

1 row inserted.
```

Как решение подойдёт только вставка из подзапроса.
Для вставки из листа `values (expr1, expr2, ...)` допускаются только выражения, которым запрос `select` не является.

Подробнее [в офф. документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423).